# ValueError: Invalid parameter for estimator Pipeline

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I get an error when tuning the hyperparameters of a decision tree with GridSearchCV.

Code is given below:

```
pipe_tree = Pipeline([
    ('Scaler', MinMaxScaler()),
    ('Classifier', DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=8))
])
```

```
# Train
pipe_tree.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

```
# Predict
pred_tree = pipe_tree.predict(X_test)
```

```
# overall accuracy score 
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
accuracy_score(y_test, pred_tree)
```

```
# Create grid parameters for hyperparameter tuning
param_dist={
    "dec_tree_criterion": ["gini", "entropy"], 
    "dec_tree_max_depth": [1,2,3,4,5,6,7, None],
    'dec_tree_min_samples_leaf': [1, 2, 3]
}
```

```
# Fit the model
grid.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Error:

```
ValueError: Invalid parameter dec_tree_criterion for estimator Pipeline(steps=[('Scaler', MinMaxScaler()),
                ('Classifier', DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=8))]). Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scikit-Learn TypeError: Invalid parameter activation for estimator Pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67747185/scikit-learn-typeerror-invalid-parameter-activation-for-estimator-pipeline)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think some part of your code is missing. I assume you are doing `RandomizedSearchCV` or similiar, but we can't see it in your code.

However, it seems that the error is in the creation of the `param_dist` dictionary. You should follow some rules to define key names. Let me recommend this [link](https://medium.com/swlh/randomized-or-grid-search-with-pipeline-cheatsheet-719c72eda68).

Basically you have to define the `param_dist` this way:

```
param_dist={
    "Classifier__criterion": ["gini", "entropy"], 
    "Classifier__max_depth": [1,2,3,4,5,6,7, None],
    'Classifier__min_samples_leaf': [1, 2, 3]
}
```

To be sure about the names you should write, ask for which possibilites you have with this code below:

```
pipeline.get_params().keys()
```